# How to create diff WPS 6.0 profiles to each WAS 6.0 Appserver Profiles?

Tags: portal, websphere-portal

Hi I had Websphere Application server 6.0 installed on Citrix box which is common to 3 users . For each user i have created different WAS profile for same installation . Now We have installed Websphere portal server 6.0 also which is also common instance to 3 users with default profile as "wp_profile" . Here i need to have 3 different WPS profiles for diff WAS profiles ?

Can any one advice .. thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set up multiple profiles with WebSphere Portal Server 6.0. Support for multiple profiles was only added in version 7.0. You will have to install WebSphere Portal separately for each user.